# Angular Bootstrap Toggle Switch

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement a toggle slider within an *ngFor based on 'yes' or 'no' values from my API. The initial toggle slider state must be checked (slider to left, or slider to the right) on the initial modal load.

I'm getting the initial state on load of my modal, but I can't slide the toggle 'yes' if the response value from the API is 'no'. I'm using Bootstrap 4, btw.

I've tried multiple variations of adding NgClass but I can't seem get this part working.

Here is what I've tried so far.

admin.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="permissionForm">
                            <div class="form-group card" *ngFor="let item of permissionsUserMap; let i=index">
                              <div class="row p-1">
                                <div class="col">
                                  <p class="d-inline">{{ item.permissionToolTip }} {{ item.hasPermission }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                  <label class="switch float-right mb-0">
                                    <input 
                                      #permissionToggle
                                      [id]="i"
                                      formControlName="HasPermission"
                                      type="checkbox" 
                                      (change)="onChangePermission($event,i)" 
                                      [value]="item.hasPermission"
                                      >
                                    <!-- <ng-container *ngIf="item.hasPermission === 'Y'">
                                      <span [ngClass]="{'input:checked,input:focus + slider round': item.hasPermission === 'Y'}"></span>
                                    </ng-container>
                                    <ng-container *ngIf="item.hasPermission === 'N'">
                                      <span [ngClass]="{'slider round': item.hasPermission === 'N'}"></span>
                                    </ng-container> -->

                                    <!-- <span *ngIf="item.hasPermission === 'Y'" [ngClass]="'slider round'">Y</span>
                                    <span *ngIf="item.hasPermission != 'Y'" [ngClass]="'noPermission round'">N</span> -->

                                    <!-- <span *ngIf="item.hasPermission === 'Y'" [ngClass]="'slider round'">Y</span>
                                    <span *ngIf="item.hasPermission != 'Y'" [ngClass]="'noPermission round'">N</span> -->

                                    <!-- <span class="slider round"></span> -->

                                    <span class="slider round" *ngIf="item.hasPermission === 'Y'"></span>
                                    <span class="noPermission round" *ngIf="item.hasPermission === 'N'"></span>
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </form>
```

admin.component.css

```
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 60px;
height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
opacity: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #ccc;
-webkit-transition: 0.4s;
transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider:before {
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 26px;
width: 26px;
left: 4px;
bottom: 4px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-transition: 0.4s;
transition: 0.4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
background-color: rgba(58,177,96,1);
}

input:focus + .slider {
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(58,177,96,1);
}
input:focus + .slider {
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(58,177,96,1);
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
-webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
-ms-transform: translateX(26px);
transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
border-radius: 50%;
}

.noPermission {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
    
.noPermission:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.noPermission.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}
        
.noPermission.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .noPermission.slider {
    background-color: rgba(58,177,96,1);
    }
    
    input:focus + .noPermission {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(58,177,96,1);
    }

input:checked + .noPermission:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried giving initial value to your formControlName? like 
`this.formBuilderInstance.group({
   HasPermission: ['Yes']
})`

Comment: @DeepakJha yes I did. My problem is, the slider doesn't slide to the right (for a Yes value) if the initial slider state is 'No' or to the left.

Comment: why you use `formControlName`? you has no a FormArray. BTW, the major problem I see is that a input type checkbox only get two values: true or false. You can use if you want `[value]="item.haspermision=='Yes'?true:false`